# Yubikey FIPS Approved Mode

Tags: yubikey, u2f

I'm having issues getting my Yubikey FIPS version to unlock and exit the FIPS approved mode.

You can see below that I first put the yubikey into fips mode by setting an admin pin. Then, I immediately try to unlock the key (to take it out of FIPS mode). Here's a rundown of the commands and output.

Anyone else run into this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. After you set a pin it never "leaves" FIPS mode as displayed from the info command.

To register the key to a website, you have to run the unlock command. Then it allows the device to complete the registration via u2f. It never gives an indication via command line other than *accepting* the pin.